# What are the rules for traveling using different movement speeds?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement

If a creature has a climb, swim, or fly speed that's lower than their base speed, how is this calculated?

For example...

If I have a base speed of 30 feet and a swim speed of 15 feet, and I'm 20 feet away from a 15 foot wide river that I have to cross. Could I do so by spending 20 feet of regular movement to arrive at the river, 15 of swim speed movement to cross the river and them have 10 feet of movement to spare. In that case, I almost doubled my normal movement by traveling a total of 35 (+10 spare) feet, despite the fact that neither of my speeds are that high.

**How exactly is speed calculated when crossed between different movement types?**